# RxJava2 multithreading or something goes wrong

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java2

Im kind of beginner at rxjava and i'm facing a problem.

I have two network calls.

```
Observable<ClassA> getClassA(){
  return networkExecutor.getClassAFromApi();
}
Observable<ClassB> getClassB(){
  return networkExecutor.getClassBFromApi();
}
```

now I need both of these in order for code to proceed, so i do a zip on them. Also I want to save those values temporary in private Class scope variables lets say cA and cB;

```
 getClassA().zipWith(getClassB, (classA, classB) -> {
  cA = classA;
  cB = classB;
  return true;
}
```

the problem is, when later on i repeat the same step, cA and cB is the old value instead of the new one.

for example first time I call zip method hashes of cA and cB are xxx1, xxx2

when i call the same method second time, new objects are generated from network with hashes xxx3 and xxx4.

when i call this class getter i get cA xxx1 instead i should already get the xxx3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in architecture, instead of setting components globaly, you should keep them in the stream creating custom class to hold the values, and take them in.
`onNext(CustomClassObject object){
    // object.getClassA;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the do operators for after the event to clear up hash fields, or clear them before you proceed with new request.
Look up [Do operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html). I would probably use doAfterNext() operator and reset the fields as necessary.